# Python: How do I declare multiple variables with given names?

Tags: python, list

For example, say I have an object with 5 attributes. How would I create 5 lists each corresponding to an attribute of the object, and the name of the lists must match those attributes. I've tried the following but it gives me a syntax error:

```
for x in A.attributes
    str(x) = [];
```

Comment: So you are trying to introduce 5 variables into current namespace?

Comment: I want the name of the lists to match because it will be easier for me for the operations that I will be performing later on on these lists.

Comment: yes I'm essentially trying to define 5 new lists within that for loop each of which should have the corresponding name.

Comment: @SKLAK: then your "names" should be keys in a dict.

Comment: @SKLAK It would help if you explain more on what you are going to do with these lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a a dict:

```
d = {}

for x in A.attributes
    d[x] = [];
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this. So there is no way to do this with lists right?

Comment: You are adding lists to your dict only. But to do the mapping with some name, dict is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
class A(object):
    pass

A.a1=[]
```

That adds a class attribute.

For an instance attribute:

```
class A(object):
    pass

t=A()
t.a1=[]
```

Or, if the attributes already exist in your instance of the object:

```
for attr, value in [(a,v) for a,v in t.__dict__.iteritems()]:
   t.attr=[]
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering the original question of the OP one could do ...

```
for x in A.attributes
    globals()[x] = []
```

But as Rohit suggests would you want to, isn't a `dict` better or perhaps the OP would like a `namedtuple`.